# tuning search on combination of float and string

Tags: sql, optimization, db2

I have this schema

```
RESTAURANT 
(id int not null,  
name varchar(50), 
place varchar(100), 
distance float,  
a varchar(50),
b varchar(50),
c varchar(50),
d varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

and I'm tuning a search function for this table.
a,b,c,d are different field used in the research, but what I need to focus on is place and the distance because most of the query are actually performed on the combination of this two field

I'm using db2, and I'm not really skilled, suggestion where to start from?

Comment: from the place (which is a string)

Comment: Depending on what they contain, all your `varchar` attributes should probably be `int` fk references to some other table.  `place` at minimum, `name` possibly.  And something still feels off about this table - if this really is storing (master data) _restaurants_, `distance` isn't an appropriate dependant attribute on `place`...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use indexes. You can execute the the Desing Advisor to see what DB2 proposes about indexes:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005144.html

For more information about indexes, you can take a look at:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/dmmag/DMMag_2010_Issue4/DataArchitect/index.html